# Microsoft Access with SQLite Back end #DELETED record problem - another solution

Tags: sqlite, ms-access

SHORT VERSION: *If all else fails, add a value (even zero) to an additional Number column in the SQLite table to stop the #DELETED demon.*

LONGER VERSION: There have been many posts about this frustrating and inconsistent problem over the years. Lord knows, I have read each one at least  half dozen times and tried every remedy proposed - and usually one of the incantations will finally solve the problem. Yet I found myself recently in a new quandary and spent the last two days racking my brain to osmose why none of the tricks worked on it.

It was classic: Access 2019 front end linked to a SQLite back end table (via the Devart SQLite ODBC driver, which I believe is inconsequential). *The table had the recommended col_ID of Number format, Auto-incrementing as the Primary Key. It had col_DateUpdated, Text format with default value of current_timestamp.* There was col_OperatorID which was Text format and the only column in a Unique Index. Finally, there were two other non-indexed Number format columns.

The table worked fine in SQLite. I could Add, Delete, Update no problem. In Access, when I opened the linked table and added a record it did not immediately show the auto incrementing value in col_ID, nor the date/time stamp. When I clicked off the row, it immediately filled all the columns of the new row with #DELETED. If I closed the table and reopened it, the new row would display just fine.

The *SQLite Pragmas were all set to Default*  including Auto Index, Normal Locking Mode and Full Synch. I tried every combination of changing the table structure, column formats, indexes, default values, etc. The problem persisted regardless of whether there was any other data in the table or not.

I've been coding in Access for over 30 years and SQLite for three and have never seen anything like it.

I was stumped until , for the heck of it, I added a value into one of the other Number columns. Amazingly, it worked great!

I can create a new row, put values in col_OperatorID AND the two non-indexed Number columns, click off the row and it takes it fine. It updates the autonumber primary key col_ID and col_DateUpdated with the current date/time just fine with no #DELETED nonsense.

It beats me why it works, maybe Access finally can accept it as a really, really unique record (even though the additiaonal data is not in any index) or maybe putting the numeric value in the other, seemingly unimportant, columns forces an update across the link, I don't know. But I thought I would pass this along because I KNOW probably forevermore, unless Microsoft or the SQLite folks come up with a cure for this, there will be people that will need this additional gimmick to get out of #DELETED hell.

Good luck and Happy Trails.

Comment: It would be better if you split this into a question and a (self-) answer. And perhaps tone down the [fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) level a few notches. ;)

Comment: Very obvious why that works - but then again, if you used Access for more then a few months, you would KNOW EXACTLY why!!! - clearly you learned nothing here.  The VERY first course you take in computing? Hint: computers store floating numbers as approximations - thus comparisons between numbers fail. There is a GAZILLION posts on SO about people seeing the message about how some one else modified the record when using linked tables to sql server (and the introduction of a timestamp column fixes this issue - do you know why? -  you should! I'll explain what is going on later today.